# PowerShell, programmatically check if a Store App (.appx) is installed

Tags: powershell, windows-store-apps, windows-store

How would I check, in PowerShell, if a specific Windows Store App is installed?
Specifically, I need to test whether the Microsoft "Terminal" app is currently installed.

Comment: Have you tried `Get-AppPackage`?

Comment: Thanks. My understanding of `.appx` packages is very primitive. I've now used `if ((Get-AppPackage).Name -like "*Terminal*") { <do-stuff> }` and that seems ok (unless you have a more efficient syntax?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to use the `-AllUsers` option to ensure you search all packages:

```
# if ((Get-AppPackage -AllUsers).Name -like "*WindowsTerminal*") {$True}
True
```